# Get intersecting point of Arc, X distance from centre (Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics

I'm no mathmetician so forgive my wording when I ask this, there is no doubt an answer somewhere but I dont even know what to search for.

[image: intersection of arc]

I want to find the intersection point (B) as a Vector2 on a perfect circle.

If I know X, Y, A and C I assume I can use the radius and distance to calulate the position of B based on the distance between X and C somehow? (using C# if there are any methods which will accomplish this)

TIA.

Comment: Is the distance YX the same as XA? Do X and A always have the same y value (are they both at the same height)?

Comment: Yes, someone informed me I can use Pythagoras, seems simple now!

Comment: I have been trying to write an answer but I'm terrible at explaining trigonometry using English :)

Comment: Me too, I think just saying Pythagoras is enough to lead to the right direction, I put my code below

Answer (score 2):

I used Pythagoras to solve it

here is the code I used:

```
    // X placement can be anywhere along the x axis of the object
    float xPlacement = Random.Range(0, obstacleWidth);
    // Get the distance from the middle of the arc as a positive number and the max height of the arc(obstacle height) 
    // Use Pythagoras to equate b
    float b = Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Pow(obstacleHeight, 2) - Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Abs((xPlacement - (obstacleWidth / 2))), 2));
    Vector2 intersect = new Vector2(xPlacement, b);
```

Comment: And if that somehow didn't work, I'm sure the SOHCAHTOA would.